# Advantages of arrow syntax in function declaration

Tags: c++, templates, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

what are the advantages of using

```
template <typename L, typename R> 
auto getsum(L l, R r) -> decltype(l + r) {return l + r;}
```

over

```
 template <typename L, typename R>
 auto getsum(L l, R r) {return l +  r;}
```

isn't it compiled into the appropriate type during template instantiation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what are the advantages of using [trailing return type syntax] ?

A possible advantage: the trailing return type is SFINAE friendly.

Your `getsum()` function, with trailing return type (`-> decltype( l + r )`), is enabled only when exist an plus operator between `l` and `r`.

If you call it with a couple of arguments that doesn't support the sum (by example, a couple of `std::vector`'s) you get a substitution failure that isn't an error (SFINAE).

So another `getsum()` function can be called.

The following is a full example that compile and where the "do something different" version is called from `getsum(a, b)`

```
#include <vector>

template <typename ... Ts>
auto getsum (Ts...)
 { /* do something different */ }

template <typename L, typename R> 
auto getsum (L l, R r) -> decltype( l + r )
 { return l + r; }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int> a, b;

   getsum(a, b);
 }
```

But if you remove the trailing return type

```
template <typename L, typename R> 
auto getsum (L l, R r) // <<--- no more tailing return type!!!
 { return l + r; }
```

the code doesn't compile anymore, because you don't have a substitution failure but an hard error.

Answer (score 5):

An advantage obviously is shorter code.

But there are disadvantages, too: besides automatic return type deduction being available from C++14 only, there are cases when the return type cannot be deduced.

Suppose the complexity of the function is increased slightly:

```
template <typename L, typename R>
auto getsum(L l, R r) {
    if (l < 0)
        return 0;
    return l + r;
}
```

Now the following won't compile:

```
int main() {
    auto s = getsum(1L, 2); // error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'int' and then 'long int'
}
```

We fix that by specifying the return type explicitly (for example, using the trailing return type syntax):

```
auto getsum(L l, R r) -> decltype(l + r) {
    if (l < 0)
        return 0;
    return l + r;
}

int main() {
    auto s = getsum(1L, 2);  // OK
}
```

Comment: But you could say `decltype(l+r) getsum(L l, R r)` without using arrow notation.

Comment: @einpoklum, no, you can't since l and r are not declared at that point. That's why it's *trailing*, you have it *after* the arguments are declared.

Comment: @MikaelH - what about `decltype( std::declval<L>() + std::declval<R>() ) getsum (L l, R r) ` ?

Comment: @MikaelH: Uh, you're right, but - what max66 said. Still, then it becomes much more cumbersome. You could do `decltype(L() + R())` I suppose, if you assume default-constructibility.

Comment: @max66, sure, but I am pretty sure I prefer `auto getsum(L l, R r) -> decltype(l+r)` in that case.

Comment: @MikaelH - I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++14 the second just a more simple version of first one.
Before the C++14 you can align function names with `auto`(so this is about codestyle).

Comment: not completely true. There are cases where the compiler cannot deduce the return type

Comment: @idclev463035818, for example?

Comment: for example when you have multiple returns that return different types (but can be converted to the return type)

Comment: @idclev463035818, if everyone is converted to one another why compiler can't use random from this types(or from the first return for example)?

Comment: @idclev463035818, answer of rustyx explain. Thanks.

Comment: @idclev463035818: That doesn't mean you need the arrow notation.

Comment: @einpoklum not even `auto` is needed, one could use `std::common_type` instead. Not sure if there is something that can only be done with the trailing return type

Comment: @idclev463035818, `decltype(l+r)` does not need to be the same as `std::common_type`, right? An addition of two `char`s would be promoted to `int`, whereas the `common_type` would obviously be `char`.

Comment: @MikaelH oh right, I read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type), but somehow I missed the "not subject to promotion" in the notes. You are right. On the other hand, if you want `char + char` to retun `char` then `common_type` is the right thing

Comment: @MikaelH anyhow my point was just that it would be possible to get rid of the `auto`, if not with `common_type` then with a different trait

Comment: @idclev463035818 - another "`decltype(l+r)` does not need to be the same as `std::common_type`" example: `l` and `r` could be objects and a defined `operator+()` could return a type that is completely unrelated.

Comment: @max66 true. I got confused by the note on cppref. I think the cases where `common_type<A,B>` actually is the same type as `A() + B()` are rare

Comment: @idclev463035818 - to get rid of the `auto` you can use `std::declval()`: `decltype( std::declval<L>() + std::declval<R>() ) getsum (L l, R r)`; it's also SFINAE friendly (but, frankly, I prefer `auto` and trailing `decltype(l+r)`).

Answer (score 1):

Your second expression might not return the same as the first. `decltype` has different deduction rules than `auto`.

To have the same return type you'd have to write this:

```
templtate <typename L, typename R>
auto getsum(L l, R r) -> decltype(auto) { return l + r; }
```

Now for the advantages of one over the other

The second snippet has the advantage of not repeating the expression. Repeating the expression can be quite cumbersome if you have complex expressions.

The advantages of the first version is that the compiler can perform SFINAE on the expression in the return type.

In C++20, you could just use concepts to constrain the function properly:

```
auto getsum(arithmetic auto l, arithmetic auto r) {
    return l + r;
}
```